# Optimization for faster numpy 'where' with boolean condition

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I generate a bunch of 5-elements vectors with

```
def beam(n):
    # For performance considerations, see
    # https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2016/06/15/faster-random-number-generation-in-intel-distribution-for-python
    try:
        import numpy.random_intel
        generator = numpy.random_intel.multivariate_normal
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        import numpy.random
        generator = numpy.random.multivariate_normal
    return generator(
        [0.0,
         0.0,
         0.0,
         0.0,
         0.0
         ],
        numpy.array([
            [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
            [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
            [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
            [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
            [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2]
        ]),
        int(n)
    )
```

This vector will be multiplied by 5x5 matrices (element wise) and checked for boundaries. I use this:

```
 b = beam(1e5)
 bound = 1000
 s = (b[:, 0]**2 + b[:, 3]**2) < bound**2
 #b[np.where(s)] (equivalent performances)
 b[s] # <= returned value from a function
```

It seems that this operation with 100k elements is quite time consuming (3ms on my machine).

> Would there be an obvious (or less obvious) way to perform this
>   operation (the `where` part, the random generation is there to give an example) ?

Comment: Which step seems unnecessarily slow to you?  `beam`? or the `s` and `b[s]` filtering?  In my tests `beam` takes 10x longer.

Comment: @hpaulj I agree, I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: `where(s)` is fast.  All methods of selecting the rows use `advanced indexing`, and takes about the same time, `b[s]`, `b[idx]`, `b[where(s)]`.  When I run it `s.all()` is True, so it has selected all rows.  So I'm doing `b[np.arange(b.shape[0])]`.  Selecting all rows individually, even in compiled code, is going to take time.

Answer (score 0):

As your components are uncorrelated one obvious speedup would be to use the univariate normal instead of the multivariate:

```
>>> from timeit import repeat
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> kwds = dict(globals=globals(), number=100)
>>> 
>>> repeat('np.random.multivariate_normal(np.zeros((5,)), np.diag((1,1,1,1,0.2)), (100,))', **kwds)
[0.01475344318896532, 0.01471381587907672, 0.013099645031616092]
>>> repeat('np.random.normal((0,0,0,0,0), (1,1,1,1,np.sqrt(0.2)), (100, 5))', **kwds)
[0.003930734936147928, 0.004097769036889076, 0.004246715921908617]
```

Further, as it stands your condition is extremely unlikely to fail. So, just check `s.all()` and if `True` do nothing.

Comment: My question was not clear, I edited. The diagonal covariance matrix and the large value for the conditions are just examples.

Comment: @CedricH. Oh for Christ's sake, it can't be that difficult to make a meaningful example, can it?!